# How can I check for an exact match in a table where each row has 70+ columns?

Tags: .net, linq, duplicates

I've been thrown into the midst of a project that has been hacked together over the past ten years. Just to make it known: I have already suggested and asked if we could refactor the database and review the architectural design of the system before we continue to develop, but multiple smaller project deliverables are "more important" than fixing the flaws in the current system.

That being said, what is the best way to check in code if there is an exact match?

Say there are 75 columns in this table, and over 2 million rows.

I know I could do:

```
var foo = bar.GetNewDocument();
dbContext.documents.Count(p => p.firstCol == foo.firstCol
                            && p.secondCol == foo.secondCol
                            && etc, etc);
```

This obviously isn't the best solution...is there a better way to compare this new entry **in code** to the rest of the entries to check for the match?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashSet<int>`, write a custom hashing method in the documents class

```
HashSet<int> hashes...;
dbContext.documents.ToList().ForEach(d=>{
  if (hashes.Contains(d.GetHash()))
    Console.WriteLine("Found one: "+d); // do further comparison here to ensure it's not hash collision
  else
    hashes.Add(d.GetHash());
});
```

Note that if dbContext.documents has way too many entries you should use `foreach` and not `.ToList` as ToList will pull them all down at once.

Also the hash method won't be accessible if you don't use `.ToList()` and try to use it directly, such as `dbContext.documents.Any(d=>d.GetHash()...)` - this won't work as it can't be translated into SQL

If this operation is performed very often you can (!) add another column that holds the hash (or add a table that holds it), this way the overhead for checking repeatedly will be very minimal - SQLServer can check 2 mln rows in an indexed columnt very, very quickly.

Comment: I just edited my post: not sure if it changes anything in your answer, but I meant 75 columns and 2 million+ rows.

Comment: @DoctorOreo it does, a little, depending on what is it you're doing. The core idea is to hash the rows, but hashing every time can be intensive. If done often enough or slow enough you can pre-compute the hashes, store them and then search them very quickly.

Comment: ... also a typical commitee that's focused on "important deliverables" will be more likely to add another hack than to refactor... even if that's how it got so ugly in the first place :)

Comment: Since hashes are not perfect, you'd want to select the documents that match that hash and *then* manually verify that they are indeed equal.  I agree that since this can't be translated to a SQL query, it's probably not the best solution.

Comment: @MikeChristensen hashes are there to remove 99.99999% of the work. While it's true they aren't perfect they can still reduce the actual full comparisons (slow) a lot. With precomputed hashes filtering out potential matches is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sql query, you need to build expression. For instance:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetEqualsExpression<T>(T obj)
    {
        var type = typeof (T);

        var x = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

        BinaryExpression body = null;
        foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var left = Expression.Property(x, propertyInfo);
            var right = Expression.Constant(propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null));
            var equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            body = body == null ? equalsExpression : Expression.AndAlso(body, equalsExpression);
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, x);
    }
```

Usage

```
        var foo = bar.GetNewDocument();
        var expression = GetEqualsExpression(foo);
        dbContext.documents.Count(expression);
```