# less expensive way to find duplicate rows in a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to find all rows in a DataTable where each of a group of columns is a duplicate.  My current idea is to get a list of indexes of all rows that appear more than once as follows:

```
public List<int> findDuplicates_New()
        {
            string[] duplicateCheckFields = { "Name", "City" };
            List<int> duplicates = new List<int>();
            List<string> rowStrs = new List<string>();
            string rowStr;

            //convert each datarow to a delimited string and add it to list rowStrs
            foreach (DataRow dr in submissionsList.Rows)
            {
                rowStr = string.Empty;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in submissionsList.Columns)
                {
                    //only use the duplicateCheckFields in the string   
                    if (duplicateCheckFields.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
                    {
                        rowStr += dr[dc].ToString() + "|";
                    }
                }
                rowStrs.Add(rowStr);
            }

            //count how many of each row string are in the list
            //add the string's index (which will match the row's index)
            //to the duplicates list if more than 1
            for (int c = 0; c < rowStrs.Count; c++)
            {
                if (rowStrs.Count(str => str == rowStrs[c]) > 1)
                {
                    duplicates.Add(c);
                }
            }
            return duplicates;
        }
```

However, this isn't very efficient: it's O(n^2) to go through the list of strings and get the count of each string.  I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584728/619177) but couldn't figure out how to use it with more than 1 field.  I'm looking for a less expensive way to handle this problem.

Comment: how many rows do you need to scan?

Comment: This may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939516/how-to-find-duplicate-record-using-linq-from-datatable

Comment: @Sachin these solutions also have O(n^2) complexity, just masked by the Linq statements

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[How can I check for an exact match in a table where each row has 70+ columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044961/how-can-i-check-for-an-exact-match-in-a-table-where-each-row-has-70-columns/16045146#16045146)

The essence is to make a set where you store hashes for rows and only do comparisons between rows with colliding hashes, complexity will be O(n)

...

If you have a **large** number of rows and storing the hashes themselves is an issue (an unlikely case, but still...) you can use a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). The core idea of a Bloom filter is to calculate [several](http://hur.st/bloomfilter?n=4&p=1.0E-20) different hashes of each row and use them as an address in a bitmap. As you're scanning through the rows you can double-check the rows that already have all the bits in the bitmap previously set.

Comment: I agree that the solution as you've presented it is O(n).  But unless I'm reading it wrong, it looks the first instance of each duplicate won't be identified as a duplicate, because it won't already be in the hashset.  For any given set of duplicate rows, I want to identify every row as a duplicate.

Comment: then use a dictionary where the key is your computed hash from all columns and the value is the row ID, this way if you find the key exists the ID that's stored with it identifies the first row of the duplicates